# Nested switch statement not running correct case code block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, switch-statement

I'm building a react app (rails backend) and have set up a nested switch case which first checks if the user has made at least a single entry, and if so, goes into a nested switch case and checks if a variable is less than 0 (basically a countdown, limiting the user to one entry a day).

The problem is, even if the condition is true (variable less than 0), it is defaulting to the 'false' case and avoiding the 'true' case. Any ideas as to what's causing this?

```
switch (this.state.getslacks.length == 0) {

  case true:

  Slack
    .create(slackParams)
    .then(data => {
      if (data.errors) {
        this.setState({
          timeout: '',
          slacks: {},
          errors: [{
            message: 'Come back tomorrow to make another entry!'
          }],
          // validationErrors: data.errors.filter(
          //   e => e.type === "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid"
          // )
        });
      } else {
        this.props.addSlack(data)
      }
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      Slack
      .all()
      .then(slacks => {
        this.setState({
          getslacks: slacks,
          loading: false
        });
      });
    }, 150)

      console.log("User's first post");
      break;

  case false:

    let latest = getslacks[0]
    let currentTime = Moment(Date()).format()
    let timeout = Moment(latest.created_at).add(20, 'hours').format()
    let elapsed = (Date() - latest.created_at)
    let timeLeft = Moment(timeout).diff(currentTime, 'hours', true)
    let timeLeftNum = parseFloat(parseFloat(timeLeft).toFixed(2))

    switch (timeLeftNum < 0) {

          ##DEFAULTING TO THIS CASE##
      case false:

        let {getslacks, loading} = this.state;
        let latest = getslacks[0]
        let currentTime = Moment(Date()).format()
        let timeout = Moment(latest.created_at).add(20, 'hours').format()
        let elapsed = (Date() - latest.created_at)
        let timeLeft = Moment(timeout).diff(currentTime, 'hours', true)
        let timeLeftNum = parseFloat(parseFloat(timeLeft).toFixed(2))
        let timeLeftString = timeLeftNum.toString()

        this.setState({
          timeout: timeLeftString,
        });

        break;

       ##THIS CASE NOT RUNNING EVEN IF CONDITION IS TRUE##
      case true:
      Slack
        .create(slackParams)
        .then(data => {
          if (data.errors) {
            this.setState({
              getslacks: [],
              slacks: {},
              errors: [{
                message: 'Come back tomorrow to make another entry!'
              }],

            });
          } else {
            this.props.addSlack(data)
          }
        });
        this.setState({
          timeout: timeLeftString,
        });

        break;
    }
      break;
}
```

Comment: can you use if-else instead of inner switch statement

Comment: Don't use `switch`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with an if-else within that initial switch. I'm still curious why it wasn't working with a nested switch though.